# Property value setting inside constructor

Tags: php, oop, properties

I am setting a property value inside constructor function like:

```
class ApiController extends Controller
   {
    protected $start;
    protected $limit;
    protected $string;

    public function __construct(Request $request) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->string = 'from: '.$this->start. ', size: '.$this->limit;
    }
```

And tried to access `$this->string` from a method inside the class like:

```
    public function test() {
        $this->start = 0;
        $this->limit = 10;
        echo $this->string;
    }
```

This echoes following output:

```
from: , size:
```

How can I set `$start` and `$limit` properties as I am trying to do.

Comment: Call `test()` in the constructor before setting `$this->string`

Comment: games of mind :) http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aa71370deafe448f25dc5231a539f6d577404691

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor,when $this-string is initialized, $this->size and $this->limit still do not have any value. You have to either set their value before you initialize $this->string or initialize $this->string after $this->size and $this->limit have value.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor function is called first, where your "string" variable (I would advise a different name btw) is set to "from: , size: ".

Then in your test() method, you set the start and limit variables, but you echo the string variable set in your construction. Your code has not updated the "string" variable with the new values!

Simple solution, move/copy you $this -> string = ... line to above your echo $this -> string line.

I hope that makes sense :)